# Why did Turbo tax provide me with form 1040 and Interest and Ordinary dividends attachment when I am filling amended tax return (1040X)?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040x, turbotax

I need to amend a return to include form 1099-R. For some reason TurboTax gave me three forms: 1040X, 1040 and Interest and Ordinary dividends attachment to form 1040. Why do I need the last two? As far as I understand I just need form 1040X to amend my tax return. What should I do with form 1040 and Interest and Ordinary dividends attachment to it?
Should I send it along my tax return? I do not have any interest or dividends earned. 
Why I wasn't provided with Interest and Ordinary Dividends attachment when I filled my 1040 for the first time, but when I amend my tax return Turbo Tax gave me it?

I was thinking that I need to send only form 1040x with form 1099-R and a check...

1099-R reports that I got money from 401(k).

Answer (score 1):

> I do not have any interest or dividends earned.

What is the 1099-R reporting?  If you received dividends from life insurance contracts or employee stock plans they are reported to you on a 1099-R and reported to the IRA on Schedule B.

> Why do I need the last two?

Along with the 1040 X *any forms or schedules that changed should be submitted*.  That's why TurboTax printed a new 1040.  The 1040X just outlines what's *different* between the original submission and this one.

If you did not include Schedule B in your initial filing (or it has changed) then you need to include it with the 1040X as well.

Comment: 1099-R reports that I got money from 401-k. I am not sure about schedule B. I had an account in foreign country, but with a very small amount - about $500. I earned some cents in interest. I mean it is tiny amount. Should I still include Schedule B?

Comment: "Schedule B" is titled "Interest and Ordinary Dividends".  If you are confident that you entered in your 1099-R correctly and you trust that TurboTax generated the forms correctly then yes you should submit it.  You should not leave off any form that has information on it or the IRS might ask you for it later (delaying your refund or increasing penalties)

Comment: @MaharajaX: you must complete part III of Schedule B (and file it) if you had any foreign account, regardless of amount; did the TurboTax printout do that and is it different from the original return? You must also include form 8938 in your income tax return (if required to file) and _separately_ file FBAR directly with FinCen if you have foreign accounts with _balance_ exceeding thresholds that are well above $500, but regardless of interest (even if _zero_ interest).